# How to stay sharp and not sleepy at work

Tags: work-environment, work-experience, work-time

I am a programmer and every morning after having breakfast at work I always feeling tired and sleepy. During breakfast I am just eating breads and scrambled egg also had 6 hours of sleep at night. I need suggestions on how to stay sharp during work hours.

Comment: More information is really going to be needed. What do you eat, how many hours do you sleep, any changes in your lifestyle (stopped with smoking? Coffee?), etc? Certain food (especially sugar for example) might give you a boost for a while, but you will crash and feel sleepy after this boost.

Comment: See https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/how-do-you-stay-productive-during-the-afternoon-energy-slump or https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10297/is-there-a-way-that-i-will-not-get-sleepy-after-lunch-while-on-my-job

Comment: Great question - wrong stack.  PS: excercise, plenty of water and moderate coffee works for me.

Comment: Do you enjoy the work you're doing?

Comment: See a doctor...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the site. It's an issue affecting your work, so it belongs here. Just because it's also on topic somewhere else doesn't mean it's not on topic here too.

Comment: I find eating bread at all during the day (even at lunch) makes me lethargic. Definitely try a different breakfast, and more time in bed (even if you're not sleeping, you're resting, which is what your body likely needs).

Comment: MatthewECornish I definitely enjoy my job.

Answer (score 4):

I often have the same problem, but I luckily found ways to deal with sleepness. You can ultimately see your doctor to get lifestyle advice before he prescribes medications.

### Work on your lifestyle

- Take care of your rest. As pointed elsewhere, 8+ hours of sleep are almost mandatory. They should however be between 7 and 9, because the older humans get, the less they sleep

Make sure you have a comfortable deep sleep. Our brain is capable of cooling down in the REM phase. If you have anything disturbing your sleep, you should sort it. A number of people need complete dark and absence of sound to sleep well. This may be hard to achieve, but you can give it a try. Not all apartments around the world have blinds, so if your curtains let some sun come in, you can try a sleeping mask.
If you have a little kid who doesn't like to sleep at night, that may be an issue for some years. Be positive, it will end once your toddler grows.

I would also recommend you to plan your sleeping time carefully. You should go to bed as soon as you are tired enough to sleep soon. I experienced that if I go to sleep too early I will wake up tired in the morning.

- Consider a shower in the morning

I mean... rather than in the evening.

But choose the right temperature. I am not suggesting a shower with **cold** water but if you try the coolest you are comfortable with you may find yourself more awake. I have no medical evidence, but it is my experience that warm combines well with sleeping. Too cold as well as too hot prevent you from sleeping when you are in the bedroom, that's why we have heaters in winter and coolers in summer

- Work your breakfast

I am going to expand on this.

I *partially* disagree with comments against caffeine. Yes, if you drink coffee in the afternoon **[AND YOU ARE NOT NATIVE OR TRAINED TO HANDLE IT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=499rwlDiAQw)**, forget about sleeping. While both tea and coffee contain caffeine, I would recommend espresso over other beverages because it is very concentrated and in my opinion (again, no medical evidence) has a *psychological* effect on the patient by stimulating his sense of taste.

There is a reason why Mediterranean breakfast is recommended by dietologists: a croissant with a juice, possibly pure, and a coffee provides you with caffeine and **carbs** useful to gather energy.

If you eat scrambled eggs, despite the bread, you are eating proteins and fats. I will ask if wholegrain bread is good or bad in this case. Anyway, protein and heavy breakfasts are enemies for your awakeness. Complex carbs, on the contrary, raise your sugar blood index quickly.

I am going to review my breakfast part with opinions from my friend who is a nutritional biologist.

### Don't necessarily try all together

I don't want you to feel discouraged or overwhelmed. Can you try one of my advices for a week? Just the coffee, or the shower, and see if it works.

I hope you can find a benefit.

Answer (score 3):

> I need suggestions on how to stay sharp during work hours.

- Eat a lighter breakfast.
- Eat a bit more mid-morning.
- Get more sleep.

If that doesn't help

- see your doctor

Answer (score 1):

I think 6 hours of sleep is way too little. Typically you need to have about 4-5 REM cycles per night, each taking about 90 minutes to complete. With that in mind, sleep needs to occur for 6-9 hours total. Usually 8 is a good number to stick with.

Also stay away from caffeine or severely limit it. While a lot of folks think caffeine makes you more alert and attentive, it has the opposite effect. It is recommended not to exceed more than 300mg of caffeine per day but that number isn't the same for everyone. Try to calculate how much caffeine you're drinking and at what times. Generally speaking, it takes about 8-12 hours for the caffeine to go away so if you should have a cut off time early in the day where you drink no more caffeine. Energy drinks and soda drinks are the worst. You can easily ingest 170mg of caffeine with Red Bull. Some energy drinks have 2x that with multiple servings per can. This can severely mess up your sleep pattern, even at the "cut off" time.

Answer (score -3):

If you're happy enough to use drugs, medikinet could work. It makes it really easy to focus on your work rather than the distractions around you.

If you don't want to do that then put some music on, with headphones if possible. That will stimulate your mind a little.

Drink lemon or grapefruit juice. There's a reason why so many people drink citrus drinks in the morning.